# How to replace jquery's live for elements that don't exist when the page is loaded

Tags: colorbox, jquery

I have seen numerous advice on stackexchange and all over the web suggesting that I not use jquery's `live` function. And at this point, [it is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/), so I'd like to get rid of it. Also I am trying to keep my javascript in one place(unobtrusive)--so I'm not putting it at the bottom of the page. I am unclear though on how to rewrite the code to avoid `live` for elements that don't yet exist on the page.

Within the javascript file for my site I have something like this:

```
 $(function() {
    $('button.test').live('click', function(){
      alert('test');
    });
 });
```

`.on(` doesn't work since the element doesn't exist yet.

The button is in a page I load in a colorbox pop-up modal window. I'm not sure exactly where that colorbox window sits in the DOM but I think it is near the top.

I could use delegate and attach this to the document--but isn't the whole point of not using `live` to avoid this?

What is the best way to get rid of `live` in this case?

Comment: `.on()` is the typical replacement for `.live()`, consult the documentation for how to use it properly. It does work quite nicely for elements that don't exist yet.

Comment: You can use delegate not attached to the document... tiz still faster

Comment: @rlemon, how would I do that?

Comment: Not a colorbox question, is it?

Comment: I think it is related to colorbox because if it weren't for the fact that the items were being loaded into a colorbox window they may have been present on the page when the document was ready and I could have attached events directly to them. Further if they weren't on the page when the page was ready some container (lower than document) may have been a good place to delegate the binding. The fact that it was colorbox made it more difficult. Also see the final solution I gave as an answer and how much it ties into colorbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.on()` - http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on("click", "button.test", function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Written this way, the element `button.test` would have to already exist

Comment: Can just as well post my fiddle here as @Zoltan beat me to the answer. http://jsfiddle.net/Hwv6q/2/

Comment: And is there any advantage to doing this than just sticking with live? Doesn't this have all of the same problems that live has?

Comment: The `.live()` will become fully unsupported in future jQuery versions, but if you're not referencing to the latest one on that particular site (i.e. http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js - which gives you the latest stable version) you can safely leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you use live() you can use die().

You can also use on() and off().

They do about the same thing but its recomended to use on.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up avoiding both `live` and an `on` attached at the document level. Here's how:

Wrap all of the jquery code specific to objects in a page which loads in the colorbox window in the function like so:

```
function cboxready(){
...
}
```

The code wrapped in this function can attach directly to the objects (instead of attaching at the document level) since it will only get run once the colorbox window is open.

Then just call this function using colorbox's callback when you attach the colorbox, like so:

```
$('a.cbox').colorbox({
    onComplete:function(){ cboxready(); }
});
```